# Random boolean for reverse value

Tags: javascript, random, boolean

Is there a more elegant way to write this code?
In my context, I would like to inverse my property **easeX** but randomly.

```
   if(Boolean(Math.round(Math.random()))){ obj.easeX = ~obj.easeX+1;};
   if(Boolean(Math.round(Math.random()))){ obj.easeY = ~obj.easeY+1;};
```

Someone has a better suggestion?
Because it is a little heavy for making a simple random reverse.
But I can't imagine another cleaner way.
I use this code in a update loop.

Comment: FWIW, it's marginally less verbose to write `if (Math.random() > 0.5)`.

Comment: You could also write
    `obj.easeX = Math.random() < 0.5 ? -obj.easeX : obj.easeX;`

Comment: thank but  ternary operator are too mutch heavy and slower performance.